# Listview in xaml doesn't fill up through local REST API call

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, uwp

I'm trying to build a Universal Windows App, with the help of an Azure Mobile Service + accompanied database. I have the following bit of code in  `ToDoList.xaml`

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="800" ItemHeight="50">
                    </WrapGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20">
                        <!--<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Complete}" Content="{Binding Text}"/>-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

With this as the code behind the class:

```
public sealed partial class ToDoList : Page
{
    ToDoListVM currentVM = new ToDoListVM();

    public ToDoList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        currentVM.getToDos();
        this.DataContext = currentVM.ToDoItems;
    }
}
```

And this is the class they're referring to for the Azure Mobile Service call:

```
class ToDoListVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems { get; set; }

    public async void getToDos()
    {
        ToDoItems = await App.MobileService.GetTable<ToDoItem>().ToCollectionAsync();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I cannot understand why the list doesn't get filled up. I start a debug instance of the service, locally, followed by starting the UWP app, though nothing appear on the screen, even though the start screen is the `ToDoList.xaml`

Another anomaly I noticed: In the `WebApiConfig` file, I changed the basic Text from the  ToDoItem to "first todo", rather than "first item". But when I try to test the API call with Postman, I still get "first item"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to populating the list view with the ItemsSource property:

```
    <ListView Name="lst">
       ...
    </ListView>
```

Then

```
public sealed partial class ToDoList : Page
{
    ToDoListVM currentVM = new ToDoListVM();

    public ToDoList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        currentVM.getToDos();
        lst.ItemsSource = currentVM.ToDoItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but so far it doesn't help. I modified the code as you said, but I still don't see anything.